# I've noticed strange votes for a specific user posts

Tags: support, flags, upvotes, voting-fraud

I've noticed some very strange upvotes for a specific user. One or more users are upvoting this user's answers.

I know that maybe this is a coincidence, but there is a huge chance that this person is trying to cheat.

How one should report these cases?

[image]

Comment: Flag for moderator attention. Looks fishy enough and has not been automatically reversed after a few days. It may be nothing, but a mod will investigate and determine if they need to escalate the issue.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Comment: I've flagged votes like this in the past (done against my account). The last time I flagged resulted in a mod message saying, and this is an actual quote: "Good for you. Keep them". Stopped knowing what counted as serial upvoting after that, but the system never kicked in in spite of being in a pattern like this. Certain types of downvote patterns don't make it react either. In general, the vote fraud detection script that auto-reverses stuff like this could really use an update. But yeah, try mod flagging and see what happens. Will be interesting to see how this is handled, not gonna lie

Comment: @Zoe Dealing with these is... tricky. Mods can't see your actual votes so if our tooling doesn't say there's something fishy there (and it's geared more towards catching sockpuppet shenanigans), we don't have any recourse but to either 1. Mark the flag handled 2. Escalate to a CM. And the CM path has a serious backlog, which makes the former option very appealing

Comment: @Machavity Can't CM's just see who voted on what? Who has access to that kind of data?

Comment: @10Rep I don't think they see it directly either (as in they don't have the same view of your votes that you get in your profile), but they have vastly better tooling to detect unusual voting patterns and deal with them. Devs have access to all the data.

Comment: Yes, this is a voting ring in action. Five upvotes within less than one minute every day for at least five consecutive days.

Comment: @PeterMortensen ha! if you look at [my rep history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat?tab=reputation) you'll see even weirder pattern. It's going for almost a year now and I was stuffed with 2 or 3 K rep points this way (_two-three thousands_ rep, go figure). Guess my account is being used to "offset" some fraudulent upvotes to other users. I flagged it (twice), I complained to mods in chat, but it looks like nobody gives a f#ck about this. At this point I feel a bit desperate

Comment: @gnat Chances are that once the ring is discovered, you'll just see them all as "User was removed". But you make a good point that this pattern on a user profile doesn't mean that the receiving user is in any way involved.

Comment: @Scratte chances are, discovery of "my" ring will take eternity. IIRC first time I flagged it was in Nov 2019 and second was in March or April this year. I think if it takes that long to handle such a blatant voting fraud then it is as if it isn't handled at all. Essentially folks who do it after it's gone can just restart and enjoy for yet another year knowing that their method gives them so much time to have fun